# Using Google Cloud Storage JSON API on localhost

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've got a python app that uses Cloud Storage client library. I'm trying to create a desktop client for an app, but I can't find which url to use to start a resumable upload.
Documentation for App engine deployed storage [here](http://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload) states:

> When you upload media, you use a special URI. In fact, methods that support media uploads have two URI endpoints:
>
> - The /upload URI, for the media. The format of the upload endpoint is the standard resource URI with an “/upload” prefix. Use this URI when transferring the media data itself. Example: POST /upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o.
> - The standard resource URI, for the metadata. If the resource contains any data fields, those fields are used to store metadata describing the uploaded file. You can use this URI when creating or updating metadata values. Example: POST /storage/v1/b/myBucket/o.

And also [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris#typical):

> For most operations you can use either of the following URLs to access objects:

```
storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>

<bucket>.storage.googleapis.com/<object>
```

But what are these urls on local machine with cloudstorage client library?

Comment: More info is needed for people to be able to help - this is very vague

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I've added information as requested.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage is fundamentally a cloud service... when you are using it you are uploading/downloading data to Google servers, and this can only be done at the googleapis.com URLs we provide.